# Excel API modifying data before storing in certain situations

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Add a table row through the excel API with a cell value of 2016-11-21T22:07:05.430Z then 0 disappears from 0Z.

Is it possible to prevent the modification of the data that is sent through to the API and store this as requested?

Note: There maybe other situations.